# Limit OrbitControls to an Area of page that does not have the Render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm an old COBOL programmer, teaching myself a bit of Javascript and Three.js for a little personal project, and I've got struck now with this doubt for almost two days. 
I've read all the questions about OrbitControls here in StackOverflow, and couldn't find anything related to what I'm trying to do. So any help would be appreciated.

I have a scene that's like the image below:

[image]

And here's what my Script Looks like right Now:

```
    var container, renderer, scene, camera, controls;
    var Main = {
        Init: function () {
            document.getElementById("comprimento").innerHTML = "Comprimento: " + localStorage.storLength / 100;
        document.getElementById("largura").innerHTML = "Largura: " + localStorage.storWidth / 100;
        document.getElementById("altura").innerHTML = "Altura: " + localStorage.storHeight / 100;
        document.getElementById("quadrado").innerHTML = "Metros²: " + localStorage.storSquare;
        Main.Render();
        Main.Camera();
        Main.Draw();
        Main.Update();
        // events
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    },
    Render: function () {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffe6ff);
        container = document.getElementById("building");
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        // Inicializacao da Cena
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
    },
    Camera: function () {
         //Inicializacao da Camera
         camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        //Posicao da Camera nos eixos X,Y,Z
        camera.position.set(0, 100, 800);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        //Controle de Camera
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        //Controle de Iluminação
        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(100, 250, 250);
        scene.add(light);
    },
    Draw: function () {
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(localStorage.storWidth, localStorage.storLength, 10, 10);
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0x888888,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
        plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add(plane);

     },
     Update: function () {
         controls.update();
         renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(Main.Update);
     }
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
Main.Init();
```

This works just fine for using the orbitControl, while the mouse is over the part where the rendered materials are.
What I'm trying to do is, limit the Orbit control functionality to only be usable while the mouse is over the little green div that is overlaying the render scene. I've tried messing up with the parameters of the OrbitControl, tried adding onMouseOver functions on the javascript, associated with the div in the html, but nothing seems to work. 
What I'm trying to do is even possible? If so, what am I missing? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you correctly, let's suppose, that you have a little green div

```
<div style="position: absolute;" id="LittleGreenDiv"></div>
```

Then you can use it as the second parameter when you create the object of controls:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, document.getElementById("LittleGreenDiv"));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/h5ghxv8s/) example.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to do. 
Thanks a lot.